# Split files and rename the files

Tags: files, filenames, split

I need to split a large file into 5 pieces and rename them.

For Example, file **Test** needs to be split into *Test1*, *Test2* & *Test3*. However, the split command splits as *xaa*,*xab*,*xbc*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next time try to read `man` page a little bit before you post question here :)

Use:

```
split -n 5 -d -a 1 Test Test
```

where

```
-n 5 -- specifies number of pieces
-d   -- forces to use number as suffix
-a 1 -- forces suffix length to 1 ( which is enough for 5 pieces )
Test -- source file
Test -- prefix
```

Comment: Sorry,  my requirement is actually to create 0test,1test,2test

Comment: @user1050619 that also is not it problem, though it wasn't specified from the beginning: use this way: `split -n 5 -d -a 1 --additional-suffix=test Test ""`

Answer (score 4):

The [`--numeric-suffixes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) should have the behaviour you are looking for.